# foreach not getting all values from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array with 15 elements. `count($array)`'s output is `15`.

But when I use the code below, it counts to 9, not 15.

```
$i = 0;
foreach($array as $value)
{
    $n = $i++;
    echo $n;
}
```

The array in question:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572993-shoping-v-dubay [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Шопинг в Дубай ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 11:35:02 +0300 ) [description] => Емирство Дубай е най-популярния шопинг център на целия Среден Изток. Известен е с моловете си, където присъстват най-големите търговски марки на пазара. Но и със своите пазари, т.нар. сукове... [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2993/thumb_medium/shoping-v-dubay.jpg?1341903321 ) [1] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572081-pravila-pri-razpolagane-na-mebeli-v-hola-za-moya-dom [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Правила при разполагане на мебели в хола - За моя дом ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 11:15:02 +0300 ) [description] => Мебелите, които ще поставите в хола си, трябва да са разположени така, че да ви бъде удобно и уютно. [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2081/thumb_medium/pravila-pri-razpolagane-na-mebeli-v-hola-za-moya-dom.jpg?1341822480 ) [2] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572957-pritchite-dobroto-nastroenie-loshoto-nastroenie-i-dashterya-im-apatiya [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Притчите: Доброто настроение, Лошото настроение и дъщеря им Апатия ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 11:10:03 +0300 ) [description] => Веднъж Доброто и Лошото настроение се срещнали и били силно привлечени едно от друго. Лошото настроение било запленено от слънчевото излъчване и ефирността на  Доброто, а то от драматизма и загадъчността на Лошото. Решили да се оженят и от брака им се родило малко момиченце - Апатия. Апатия пораснала твърде бързо и дали заради грешки във възпитанието или поради несполучлива комбинация на гени, се превърнала в сериен убиец... [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2957/thumb_medium/pritchite-dobroto-nastroenie-loshoto-nastroenie-i-dashterya-im-apatiya.jpg?1341901946 ) [3] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1571565-krasivasi-dieta-s-papesh [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => krasivasi: Диета с пъпеш! ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:55:02 +0300 ) [description] => Тази диета ще ви помогне да се освободите от 3-4 нежелани килограма, само за 3 дни. [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/1565/thumb_medium/krasivasi-dieta-s-papesh.jpg?1341762339 ) [4] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572883-zadarzhasht-sprey-za-udalzhavane-na-poloviya-akt-blog-za-mazhko-polovo-zdrave [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Задържащ спрей за удължаване на половия акт | Блог за Мъжко Полово Здраве ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:50:01 +0300 ) [description] => Експериментален спрей за забавяне на еякулацията прилаган пет минути преди секс, помага на мъжете да преодолеят преждевременната еякулация. Това потвърждават последните изследвания в областта. Спрей наречен PSD502, съдържа анестетици като лидокаин и прилокаин. Уникалното при този спрей е, че той .... [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2883/thumb_medium/zadarzhasht-sprey-za-udalzhavane-na-poloviya-akt-blog-za-mazhko-polovo-zdrave.jpg?1341898251 ) [5] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572812-kris-braun-s-parvi-1-album-vav-velikobritaniya-i-poreden-v-sasht [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Крис Браун с първи №1 албум във Великобритания и пореден в САЩ | ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:45:01 +0300 ) [description] => Албумът Fortune на американската R&B, хип-хоп и рап звезда Крис Браун, издаден на 3 юли 2012 година, оглави класациите за най-продавани във Великобритания и Америка [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2812/thumb_medium/kris-braun-s-parvi-1-album-vav-velikobritaniya-i-poreden-v-sasht.jpg?1341871551 ) [6] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572124-ludogorets-lokomotiv-plovdiv-superkupa-2012 [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Лудогорец - Локомотив Пловдив І Суперкупа 2012 ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:10:01 +0300 ) [description] => Двубоят между Лудогорец и Локомотив Пловдив за Суперкупата на България ще се изиграе на стадион Лазур в Бургас. Срещата ще бъде предавана пряко по канала на цифровия оператор "Булсатком" – ТВ+. Тимът от Разград постигна исторически дубъл през миналия сезон, като спечели "А" група и вдигна Купата на България. В този случай по регламент в мача за Суперкупата на страната шампионът трябва да се изправи срещу финалиста за Купата. Любопитното е, че стадионът на Черноморец прие и финала за Купата на България, в който Лудогорец обърна пловдивския Локо за 2:1 и триумфира с трофея. [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2124/thumb_medium/ludogorets-lokomotiv-plovdiv-superkupa-2012.jpg?1341824396 ) [7] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572888-za-stabilizirane-na-kravnoto-nalyagane-pri-sardechnosadovi-problemi [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => За стабилизиране на кръвното налягане, при сърдечносъдови проблеми! ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 10:05:02 +0300 ) [description] => от рецептите на баба: Рецептата се използва за стабилизиране на кръвното налягане при сърдечносъдови заболявания, импотентност, фригидност и лечение аденом на простата. Използва се спиртен извлек от [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2888/thumb_medium/za-stabilizirane-na-kravnoto-nalyagane-pri-sardechnosadovi-problemi.jpg?1341898654 ) [8] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1571598-parvite-patsienti-na-mobilen-stomatologichen-kabinet-poluchiha-bezplatni-protezi [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Първите пациенти на мобилен стоматологичен кабинет получиха безплатни протези ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 08:50:01 +0300 ) [description] => Мобилният стоматологичен кабинет на фондация „Св. Иван Рилски” преглежда пациенти вече и в селата Ясен, Подем и Върбица. И там на нуждаещите се възрастни хора ще бъдат поставени зъбни протези, дарени от фондацията. Следващите пациенти на д-р Петева и д-р Найденова ще бъдат от село Рибен... [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/1598/thumb_medium/parvite-patsienti-na-mobilen-stomatologichen-kabinet-poluchiha-bezplatni-protezi.jpg?1341768583 ) [9] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1571730-mneniya-na-potrebiteli-izprobvali-santament-otzivi-i-komentari-santament-produkt-za-profilaktika-i-lekuvane-na-ustnata-k [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Мнения на потребители изпробвали Сантамент. Отзиви и коментари. Сантамент - продукт за профилактика и лекуване на устната кухина ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 08:45:01 +0300 ) [description] => Отзиви на наши потребители Здравейте, на 34г.съм страдам от парадонтоза която е около 50%. Нямам клатещи зъби, но имам оголване на предени зъби. На скоро започнаха болки в венеца от горе в ляво и стоматолога каза че имам много голям джоб и от там ми идват болките. Изписа антибиотик, но въпреки това не намаляха болките. Болеше ме все едно зъб боли. Започнах да пия обезболяващи. Веднъж една приятелка ми препоръча Сантамента, нейната стоматоложка и го препоръчала, лекувала много бързо афтите с него. На нея й го изписала след зъбна операция. Поръчах го от вас и започнах да жабуркам сутрин обед и вечер интензивно Веднага след като започнах да го ползвам спряхя да ме болят венците а джобовите изчезнаха.Освен това лекувам афтите на дъщеря ми, която често страда от тях и мъжа ми го ползва за гърло, както бяхте ми препоръчали. Запалих всичките ми приятелки Много сме доволни! Страхотен препарат! Благодаря ви! ! Здравейте, дълги години се "боря" с парадонтозата лайка,... [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/1730/thumb_medium/mneniya-na-potrebiteli-izprobvali-santament-otzivi-i-komentari-santament-produkt-za-profilaktika-i-lekuvane-na-ustnata-kuhina.jpg?1341806662 ) [10] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1571899-koy-palnee-po-barzo-zhenite-ili-mazhete [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Кой пълнее по-бързо, жените или мъжете? ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 08:40:01 +0300 ) [description] => Последните проучвания на американските специалисти психолози констатираха, че женският мозък е така устроен, че му е по-трудно да се бори с апетита. Според последните статистики жените дебеланки са с цели 25% повече отколкото мъжете. Учените са на мнение, че това се дължи преди всичко на по-слабата воля и стреса в ежедневието на жената. Жените като цяло по-често прибягват до ползването на диети спрямо мъжете и по-малко се упражняват физически. Експериментът, на който били подложени мъжете и жените доброволци е бил да стоят гладни осемнайсет часа, а през това време е трябвало да изпълняват различни физически натоварвания. [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/1899/thumb_medium/koy-palnee-po-barzo-zhenite-ili-mazhete.jpg?1341817785 ) [11] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572003-vnimanie-skriti-maznini [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Внимание: Скрити мазнини ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 08:35:01 +0300 ) [description] => В стремежа си да не пълнеем си купуваме само обезмаслено мляко и напълно се отказваме от кравето масло, но често напълно забравяме за продуктите, съдържащи т.нар. скрити мазнини. Изчислено е, че 25-30 г мазнини е дневният максимум за хората с наднормено тегло. Именно това количество е достатъчно на организма за обменните процеси, строежа и обновяването на клетките. [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2003/thumb_medium/vnimanie-skriti-maznini.jpg?1341819984 ) [12] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572223-9-yuli-mozhe-da-e-den-na-internet-sriv [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => 9 юли може да е ден на интернет срив ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 08:20:01 +0300 ) [description] => Ако днес не сте успели да влезете в интернет от личния  или от служебния си компютър, то може би сте жертва на вирус.Както Медиапул информира, според редица експерти днешният 9 юли 2012 година, може да се окаже ден на изпитание за интернет потребителите. Денят  на Страшния съд за интернет, го нарича не на шега в. "Кориере дела сера". Десетки хиляди хора, чиито компютри са били заразени с вирус, открит през 2007 г. и наречен DNS Changer, са заплашени да не могат да влязат в интернет след 4 ч. по Гринуич тази нощ, този вирус отклонявал трафика към незаконни, учишлено манипулирани сайтове, така че киберпиратите да могат да "оберат" потребителите.  9 юли 2012 е денят, в който изтича срока на антивирусната програма , разработена от американското ФБР, посочва Франс прес, цитирана от БТА. Миналият ноември шест киберпирата от естонски произход и един руснак бях обвинени, че са разпространили вируса. Възможно е той да е нанесъл щети на 4 милиона компютри по света. След като конфискува сървър... [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2223/thumb_medium/9-yuli-mozhe-da-e-den-na-internet-sriv.jpg?1341828319 ) [13] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1572559-krasivoto-si-e-krasivo-marmalad-net [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Красивото си е красиво | Marmalad.net ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Tue, 10 Jul 2012 08:15:01 +0300 ) [description] => Добавете ни и във Фейсбук. Приятен и усмихнат ден! :) 09.07.2012г. [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/2559/thumb_medium/krasivoto-si-e-krasivo-marmalad-net.jpg?1341845034 ) [14] => Array ( [link] => http://site.com/1571798-dati-za-startirashti-kursove-po-shema-az-moga-poveche [title] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Дати за стартиращи курсове по схема Аз Мога Повече ) [pubDate] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => Mon, 09 Jul 2012 22:55:01 +0300 ) [description] => Ако сте получили своето Уведомление по схема Аз Мога Повече, и търсите одобрен доставчик на обучение от Агенцията по Заетостта, предлагаме на вашето внимание да разгледате курсовете, които стартират през лятото. Успех и на тези, които все още очакват одобрени от Агенцията по Заетостта. Изберете си доставчик на обучение предварително, за да не губите време при одобрение. [img] => http://site.com/attachments/stories-photos/0157/1798/thumb_medium/dati-za-startirashti-kursove-po-shema-az-moga-poveche.jpg?1341813367 ) )
```

Comment: please put the array here too.

Comment: That will count to 14 as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I setup [a test case on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/p4BwLdvE) that runs as expected:

```
Count is 15
0 => 1
1 => 2
2 => 3
3 => 4
4 => 5
5 => 6
6 => 7
7 => 8
8 => 9
9 => 0
10 => 1
11 => 2
12 => 3
13 => 4
14 => 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `$i` starting off at 0. That's why. Start `$i` off as `1` to see `$n`==`15`.

Comment: if i print some data from the array is only to 9 not all of them

Comment: how are you printing the data?

Comment: echo $array['link']; inside the foreach and it shows only 9 links instead of 15

Comment: Try doing a `print_r($array)` inside the `foreach` to see if all of the 1st dimension elements have the `link` key.

Comment: I think it must be print_r($value) because it is a nested array

Comment: Wooops, @Sarah is right. Don't do `print_r($array)` but `print_r($value)` instead.

Comment: @MarianPetrov That's very unusual, post all of your exact code.

Comment: its simple $data = the array foreach($data as $value){echo $value['title']} this shows 9 title instead of 15

Comment: Code doesn't just mess up like that. There must be something that you're missing. Is that your **exact** code? In the whole document/included files? Something, somewhere is messing it up. You need to find out what that is.

Comment: @MarianPetrov run `var_export($array);` and edit your post with the result. I'll check this out for myself.

Comment: it just show the data .. but the interesting thing is that now it shows all of them. Hmm i think the problem was one of the values since i get the data from rss feed and there was alt tag and it was like this alt=""some text"" and for some reason it may stop the loop